# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast - FLUTTER

Tags: string, list, flutter, mobile, casting

This icon button, once pressed, opens a howOkCancelAlertDialog and if you click on ok, a showTextInputDialog opens, assigning the input entered from the keyboard to the input variable which is of the List  type.

```
IconButton( icon: const Icon(FeatherIcons.arrowRight, color: Colors.black,),
                      onPressed: () async {
                              final result = await
                              showOkCancelAlertDialog(
                              context: context,
                              title: 'Change or Create a new Password',
                              message:
                              'This will remove your existing Password or create a new one',
                               );
    
                              if (result == OkCancelResult.ok) {
    
                                final input = await showTextInputDialog(
                                  textFields: [DialogTextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                  context: context,
                                  title: 'Change or Create a new Password',
                                  message: 'enter your new password',
                                );
                                print ("PROVAA PRIMA DELL IF"+input.toString());
                                
                                  context.read<SettingsBloc>().changePassword(input as String);
                                    SettingsPage.inputPassword = input as String;
                                     SettingsPage.inputPassword = tec.text;
                                  setState(() {
                                    encryptedText = encryptAES(SettingsPage.inputPassword);
                                     print("PROVA ENCRYPTED TEXT "+encryptedText);
                                  });
                                     prefs.setString('savedPass', encryptedText);
                                     encryptedText = decryptAES(encryptedText);
                                     print("PROVA TESTO DECRIPTATO " + encryptedText);
                              }
                            },
                          ),
```

In execution, however, I get this error because this variable of type List  cannot be assigned to variables of type String. Can you help me solve this problem and make sure that I can assign the input without getting any kind of problem in execution?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [showTextInputDialog](https://pub.dev/documentation/adaptive_dialog/latest/adaptive_dialog/showTextInputDialog.html) documentation, it's clear that it returns List.

You can't convert that to String using:

```
input as String
```

You need to access the values through index, in your case you can use:

```
input.first as String
```

Comment: with this access, i got the seguent error : RangeError (start): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -16

Comment: @SimoneSpagnolo How did you access the value? Did you use the exact code ?